# View/Page with form to insert data and display it

Tags: views

I need to create a View/Page or whatever to display a form. This form only could be viewed by registered users, and on it, the user could insert different data (text, images, etc) and then this data need to be displayed on another view/page/section of the web.

I think this is very simple to do it with Drupal, but I'm a little lost, and I need a guide or some advice to go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to [create a content type](https://drupal.org/node/774728) and [add some fields to it](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui).

After that [configure permissions](https://drupal.org/getting-started/6/admin/user/permissions) so authenticated users can create that content.

The follow up display of that content can probably most easily be done with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.